# Any simple way to add total number of observations on to density plot for each group and facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can manage to do this so far:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, fill=fill)) + 
  geom_density(alpha=0.3) + 
  stat_vline(aes(color=fill), xintercept="mean", linetype="dotted") +
  facet_grid(y ~ z , labeller=label_both ) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels=comma) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,48000), ylim=c(0, 3e-4)) +
  geom_text(y=2e-4, aes(label=..count.., ymax=..count.., color=fill),
            position=position_dodge(width=15000), 
            stat="bin", binwidth=100000, origin=-50000+35000)
```

As you can see `geom_text` is very complicated. I chose `bin` as my stats layer and provide a very large `binwidth` so that only 1 bin is produced, and I have to provide a good `origin` so that the values are actually printed inside the plot. Also, I have to manually adjust `width` of `dodge` as the `bin` interval is crazy.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it is worth putting this info in the plot titles... but manually inserting text is always difficult when facetting.

Comment: So what's the problem? Care to provide some sample data?